# How to emit multiple different state at a time in bloc pattern flutter

Tags: flutter-bloc

1. [My cubit class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH97V.png)
2. [My cubit state class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g36pB.png)
3. [My screen code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLDp8.png)
   When i emit two different state anywhere like i am doing during initialization of bloc
   [I am doing two mint at initialization of cubit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbKrz.png)
   then only last emit was reflect in screen , In my case only GetCount state Worked . GetString state never called.
   i want to reflect all emit which i call in initial state work fine .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I see you're new, so some friendly advice… please improve your question to make it easier for people to assist you. As a minimum, you should include relevant code as text within the question, not as links or screenshots. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Once you have done that, there might be further requests from users who are familiar with the subject you're asking about, and who can guide you on what additional specific information might be required. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

first of all remove `buildWhen` in screen code.

second, you can add line:

```
emit(first state);
await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200));
emit(second state);
```

you can find more info [here](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/2094)